Should the arguments received by a solidity function always have the same value as the arguments passed from client side ethers Contract method call?
I have created a signature from a digest client side that successfully recovers the signer address as RecoveredAddress of the signed digest. When I send a transaction to the solidity verification function which accepts the arguments of (address owner, bytes signature, bytes32 digest) from the client, I immediately logged the arguments on the solidity side before any processing to ensure that the proper arguments were received but they are different than what was passed to the function?
I attemped to pass arguments from the client side to a solidity function using an ethers Contract instance that calls the verify method, but the arguments passed to the function are different upon arrival to the function as the are emitted in the event logs that are place as first components of the function call. Notice the immediate logging of the passed arguments to the function which are not the same as what was passed? I am I doing something wrong are is the data being mutated during the call from the ethers method on the back end?
// Solidity function to verify the signature
function verifyFunc(
address owner,
bytes memory signature,
bytes32 digest
) public returns (bool) {
emit AddressLogged(owner);
emit SignatureLogged(signature);
emit HashLogged(digest);

// Bypassing internal Solidity hash calculation to validate computed client-side data
address recoveredAddress = verifySignature(digest, signature);
if (recoveredAddress != owner) {
    emit InvalidRecoveredAddress(recoveredAddress);
    return false;
} else {
    emit AddressRecovered(recoveredAddress);
}
}

// Function to recover the address from the signature
function verifySignature(bytes32 digest, bytes memory signature) public pure returns (address) {
return ECDSA.recover(digest, signature);
}

const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum, "any");
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
const signer = await provider.getSigner();
const address = await signer.getAddress();

if (!/^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$/.test(address)) {
throw new Error("Invalid address format");
}

const digest = ethers.utils.arrayify(hashToSign);
console.log('Digest:', ethers.utils.hexlify(digest));

const signature = await signer.signMessage(digest);
console.log('Received Signature:', signature);

const recoveredAddress = ethers.verifyMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(digest), signature);
if (recoveredAddress.toLowerCase() === address.toLowerCase()) {
console.log('Signature is valid and matches the address:', address);
} else {
console.error('Signature does not match the address.');
}

const signer1 = new ethers.Wallet(privatekey, provider);
const tokenAddress = "0x...";

const tokenAbi = {
"inputs": [
    {
        "internalType": "address",
        "name": "owner",
        "type": "address"
    },
    {
        "internalType": "bytes",
        "name": "signature",
        "type": "bytes"
    },
    {
        "internalType": "bytes32",
        "name": "digest",
        "type": "bytes32"
    }
],
"name": "verifyPermitBatch",
"outputs": [
    {
        "internalType": "bool",
        "name": "",
        "type": "bool"
    }
],
"stateMutability": "nonpayable",
"type": "function"
};

const tokenAbiVerifySignature = {
"inputs": [
    {
        "internalType": "bytes32",
        "name": "digest",
        "type": "bytes32"
    },
    {
        "internalType": "bytes",
        "name": "signature",
        "type": "bytes"
    }
],
"name": "verifySignature",
"outputs": [
    {
        "internalType": "address",
        "name": "",
        "type": "address"
    }
],
"stateMutability": "pure",
"type": "function"
};

const Token = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, [tokenAbi, tokenAbiVerifySignature], signer1);

const tx = await Token.verifyPermitBatch(address, signature, digest, {
gasLimit: 750000,
maxFeePerGas: maxFeePerGas,
maxPriorityFeePerGas: maxPriorityFeePerGas,
});

console.log('Transaction sent:', tx.hash);

const receipt = await tx.wait(1);
console.log('Transaction receipt:', receipt);
receipt.logs.forEach(log => {
const parsedLog = eventInterface.parseLog(log);
console.log('Decoded Log:', parsedLog);
});

Console.log
Signer address: 0xabcdefg7ad71A5A3aEbF929B4E39AacC23b30B0c
Hash to sign: 0xc3ea7127e1631e27bdaceef454a7e781cb22235f8bbfb788c19fe3494883d4f2 

    Received Signature:   0xacb99316f84654aa29874c237f10acf8b8f95a79dd47141d9b4b3b7427b9fbac5a6c95d7bf683227b984d756aafce994587c1ee8a5c90 
5f41a1f0edbf0ebf9331b 

Signature is valid and matches the address: 0xabcdefg7ad71A5A3aEbF929B4E39AacC23b30B0c

//NOTICE THAT ALL ARGUMENTS PASS DIRECTLY TO SOLIDITY FUNCTION DO NOT MATCH
Decoded Log: 
Object { fragment: {…}, name: "AddressLogged", signature: "AddressLogged(address)", topic: 
"0x36341629533027a87dbcdf4df3be2c81bf2b9e23f8d33eb2b6903f9b873a9fe8", args: Proxy }


 //SIGNATURE IS NOT CORRECT OR THE CORRECT LENGTH
Decoded Log: 
Object { fragment: {…}, name: "SignatureLogged", signature: "SignatureLogged(bytes)", topic: 
"0x04634f62df3e49b268cd707758d24bdf4e7c1998ec4b03d9edb12f6ee57eba0f", args: Proxy }


//HASH IS DISPLAY DIFFERENT FROM HASH PASSED THAT IS IMMEDIATELY LOGGED AFTER INPUT
Decoded Log: 
Object { fragment: {…}, name: "HashLogged", signature: "HashLogged(bytes32)", topic:
"0xdc7bac3048a782a7fe02ea91f7aee3a7afd2ada6752d98756c99ad00c34b2ea9", args: Proxy }


//SIGNATURE RECOVERY FAILURE AS ARGUMENTS PASS ARE NOT THE SAME AS CALCULATED CLIENT SIDE
Decoded Log:
Object { fragment: {…}, name: "InvalidRecoveredAddress", signature: "InvalidRecoveredAddress(address)", 
topic: "0x1881324958f5516d2a7001f234662202e284d65459abc9edf891fb1b579759b7", args: Proxy }

